# mySQL: Not wanted cast to integer in search query

Tags: mysql, search, casting, integer

today i found issue with in one search query and i can't find easy solution.

We have query:

```
SELECT 
   invoice_id, firstname, lastname 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
   email = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   firstname = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   lastname = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   invoice_id = '24assets@example.com'
```

the problem here is that we have search by `invoice_id` - int(10) UNSIGNED.

Mysql automatically cast 24assets@example.com to integer: 24 and show results for row with invoice_id = 24

The only solution that i found is to check is number or not before send to SQL query and if is not number to execute another query not containing invoice_id inside.

This is example query, the real query have 3 JOIN's by this invoice_id

Its was very surprised to see result: **24** when execute this query the first time:

```
SELECT invoice_id FROM table WHERE invoice_id = '24aaa@aaa.aa'
```

i didn't know about this cast before, because normally not searching stings in integer column then i read in google about that.

Comment: I didn't know either. My first idea would be to cast `invoice_id`, so `WHERE CAST(invoice_id as VARCHAR) = '24aaa@aaa.aa'`. But even if that works, it might be bad for the use of indexes and therefor for the performance of your query. But you could test it. Maybe it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work but I think handling it in your code (php I assume?) would be clearer.

**Complex workaround:**

```
SELECT 
   invoice_id, firstname, lastname 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
   email = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   firstname = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   lastname = '24assets@example.com' OR 
   invoice_id = concat('','24assets@example.com' * 1)
```